# Delayed job not sending mails - How to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have delayed job setup with the following settings:

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 120
```

I have started a worker, working in development and have configured ActionMailer to send mail.

Also I call it with the following in my controller:

```
OrderMailer.delay.order_notification(@order)
```

I can see the jobs created in Mongo, they dont show any errors in the console, how do I find out if there were any errors?? Is there some kind of job log?

I get the following in console:

```
1 jobs processed at 3.6244 j/s, 0 failed ..
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, did you manage to fix your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

there should be a `log/delayed_job.log` which lists the jobs processed.  You can also use the database to access the errors for failed tasks.

```
>> failed_jobs = Delayed::Job.where('attempts > 0')
>> failed_jobs.first.last_error
```

Comment: failed_jobs returns 0, so the job is seen as a success, yet the mail is not delivered.

Comment: then the error is in your mailer not dj. turn error debugging in action mailer on.  add this in your config file `config.raise_delivery_errors = true`

Comment: config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true , btw the mail sends when i disable dj.

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to debug DelayedJob is the gem **Delayed Job Web** (see https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web), which gives you a "*Resque like web interface for delayed job*", accessible via `http://localhost:3000/delayed_job`. The interface provides a "Failed Jobs"-Tab, where you can investigate the "last error"-Field more conveniently than in the terminal...